# How save many records like (date) in one field in Access Database..?

Tags: database, ms-access

Dears,
I have create table and form that contains "Renew time" field, I want to save Date and Time in one field and in each time when I want to update and save the old record not erase it but keep it in database (Accumulation of value)... I need your Help.

Comment: Not a real solution, so only a comment: DON'T store multiple values in one field, it's more trouble than it's worth. Instead, create a history table where you store the ID of the row and the dates it has been updated.

Comment: If you really, really want this, explore memo type field and ColumnHistory property - but I don't recommend, just saying it's there.

Comment: I have many names and each one  should be have renew time during year so is it possible to create history table time for each name?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please show us what tables and forms you have and your desired output.